# Can I extend SharePoint 2013 Rest API?

Tags: custom, rest

I'm working in a big project in SharePoint 2013 and I will use SharePoint 2013 for back-end activities (create list, manage workflow, manage user profile etc.).

I would extend default SharePoint's Rest API with my custom API to serve best front-end. I know that with SharePoint I can use default Rest API simply like that:

```
http://server/site/_api/
```

With SharePoint, can I do something like that:

```
http://server/site/_api/CustomApi
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've followed this post: http://jbarkes.blogspot.it/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-create-custom-wcf-rest.html

Thanks

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 8):

Yes you can extend the REST API:

Here are the high level steps of what you must do:
Create a class decorated with ClientCallableType

Add methods and properties to the class, decorate with ClientCallable, ClientCallableMethod, ClientCallableProperty

Create the Object Factory that inherits from ClientCllableObjectFactory (this will create an class instance using an identifier)

Create a ServerStub class that inherits from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub

Create another class in a .Client namespace

Create a ScriptTypeFactory that implements the IScriptTypeFactory interface

For detailed steps and working example follow:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Extending-SharePoint-2013-c39d01ae

http://www.silver-it.com/node/160